# How to find $rk(x+2y-4z)$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm currently studying for a test on Friday. I'm doing the following exercise:

> Find the dimension of $$P = \big\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^{3} \mid x+2y-4z=0\big\}$$

We know that

$$f\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\\\end{pmatrix} = x+2y-4z$$

is linear and that $P = \ker(f)$. So, thanks to the rank–nullity theorem, we can say that

$$\dim(\mathbb{R}^{3}) = rk(f) + \dim(\ker(f))$$

In class we said that the rank has something to do with the surjectivity of $f$. However I still cannot figure it out. Thanks.

Comment: Your approach seems very unusual to me, but I do like it.

Comment: @Servaes still learning haha, if you have an other method i'd be glad to know it

Comment: Write $f$ as a matrix multiplication. Does that give you any ideas about its rank?

Answer (score 1):

$P = \big\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^{3}\ |\ x+2y-4z=0\big\}$

So we can notice that the set $P$ is a plane in $\mathbb R^3$ since it have the equation $x+2y-4z=0$, thus $dim(P)=2$

$P$ is a vector space also since $O(0,0,0) \in P$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Note that $\operatorname{rk}(f)=\dim(\operatorname{im}(f))$.

Alternatively, it is clear that $\dim P<3$ because $P\subset\Bbb{R}^3$ and $(x,y,z)=(1,0,0)\notin P$. Because $(2,-1,0),(0,2,1)\in P$ and these two vectors are linearly independent, we see that $\dim P=2$.